# Ehcache Distributed Multiple channel

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I am using ehcache in ditributed mode . 
The caches are synchronized by channel .

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="channelName=CHANNEL1:connect=UDP(mcast_port=45568)"
    propertySeparator=":" />
```

For a new requirement , i need to synch with two channels : CHANNEL1 and CHANNEL2 .

Is this possible ? if yes , how i can do that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually One instance of cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory is used to replicate ( or Synchronize)  number of caches across cluster. In that case, `"channelName=CHANNEL1:"` is more like simply giving a name. I don't think ehCache supports multiple channels.

If you're requirement is to have some replication specific one channel, you can try one of the following

- Run two EhCache Managers in the same application each with it's ehcache.xml, One for the specific replication logic, and one for the common replication logic of caches.
- You will have only one cache manager, but your ehcache.xml will vary in a way that, you won't include the cache ( which requires specific replication logic) with in the third application.

First one is more cleaner approach.
You can have multiple EhcacheManagers with Spring in following way,

```
<ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager1" />

<bean id="ehCacheManager1" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache-1.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="ehCacheManager2" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache-2.xml" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I need to keep the CHANNEL1 and CHANNEL2 because there is some synch that must be done only for one channel

Comment: If you want some replication specific to one channel, and then when you are saying "I need to synch with two channels : CHANNEL1 and CHANNEL2"

How can you have both Channels replicated, Do you mean replicate all except some caches ? Can you give exact usecase.

You could do this, Keep one channel for the common things, and the other  two ( channel1 and channel2) specific to them !!!

Comment: I have 3 applications deployed in Websphere cluster . A1 , A2 and A3 . The actual Situation is that every application have a Distributed EHcache and the synch is done with Jgroup using CHANNEL . Now i ,have a new cache that must be shared by the 3 applications . So i need to keep my existing cache synch only for a single application and the new cache must be synch cross applications . How we can do that ?

Comment: My question was about how technically you do that , i don't find any way todo what you are saying in the ehcache.xml file

Comment: this is not working , i implement this and i got this as a message : WARN  UDP User: Ip: - JGRP000012: discarded message from different cluster CHANNEL3 (our cluster is CHANNEL1). Sender was xxxxxx

Comment: The problem was the two channel had the same mcast port , if you put differents value all is working , thanks